# Is there a way to instead of going for another activity when a button is pressed, it expands and show new options?

Tags: android, button, android-activity, expand

I am sure this can be a little hard to understand through words so I'll try my best.
What I want is that when a button is pressed, instead of going to a whole new page, it just expands and shows some options, I tried uploading some pictures, but apparently, I need more reputation to do that.

Pictures on imgur (the first one is the menu, the second one is after one of the buttons are pressed:
[image]

Second: https://i.stack.imgur.com/05W0w.jpg

Comment: You can link to imgur uploaded pics and someone with higher rep can embed them for you. Back on topic, you can do anything you want to with Android, some things do take more work though.

Comment: You may be able to use an [ExpandableListView](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/270612-how-to-get-started-with-expandablelistview/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you want an expandable listview?

if you mean this ,  I think this two open source project can help you .

https://github.com/guohai/and-expandable-listview

https://github.com/tjerkw/Android-SlideExpandableListView

if you mean you really want an activity when you click the button.

you can learn [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) from official document.